# How can I optimize calculation of mean in pyspark while ignoring Null values

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql, missing-data

I have a Pyspark Dataframe with around 4 billion rows, so efficiency in operations is very important. What I want to do seems very simple. I want to calculate the average value from two columns, and if one of them is Null I want to only return the non-null value. In Python I could easily accomplish this using np.nanmean, but I do not believe anything similar is implemented in Pyspark.

To clarify the behavior I am expecting, please see the below example rows:

```
user_id    col_1    col_2    avg_score
1          32       12       22
2          24       None     24
```

Below is my currently implementation. Note that all values in col_1 are guaranteed to be non-null. I believe this can probably be further optimized:

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as f_

spark_df = spark_df.na.fill(0, 'col_2')
spark_df = spark_df.withColumn('avg_score',
    sum([spark_df[i] for i in ['col_1','col_2']) /
    sum([f_.when(spark_df[i] > 0, 1).otherwise(0) for i in ['col_1','col_2']]))
```

If anyone has any suggestions for whether there is a more efficient way to calculate this I would really appreciate it.

Comment: Average for each column? or merged?

Comment: I am trying to calculate the average value for each row. To attempt to clarify my question I have modified the main text.